# How do I leave Google+?

Tags: google-plus, account-management

I joined up with Google+ and am finding it's not to my tastes and I don't find it useful.

How the heck do I leave Google Plus?

I cannot find an opt-out link for the life of me. It bothers me that I now have a social network bound to my "Google" identity.

Anyone know how I can leave Google+? Or where I can delete my G+ profile?

Comment: Here is a YouTube video that purports to show the [process for leaving Google+](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKq0bvKNy7k).

Comment: Here are the official instruction's from Google+'s online documentation: - [Deleting my Google+ profile](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1044503?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 27):

You might be able to go to the [Account Management page](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/ManageAccount) then scroll down to "My Products" click edit. There might be something along the lines of "Remove Google+"

**EDIT:** Perhaps you should have done a google search. I just did it and I found [this](http://www.troublefixers.com/how-to-delete-google-plus-or-google-account-safely-without-deleting-google-or-gmail-account/) link. Clearly written instructions on how to delete Google+.

**Step 1:** Click on Settings icon on the top right of the Google Plus screen when you are logged in and click on `Google+ Settings`

[image: Step 1 - Removing Google+]

**Step 2:** Click on the Account Overview Link in the left pane and the click on the link towards the bottom of this page which says `Delete profile and social features – Delete Profile and associated social features`

[image: Step 2 - Removing Google+]

**Step 3:** On next screen, select the option which says `Delete Google+ Content` **IMPORTANT**. Then click the check box at the bottom of the page which says `I understand that deleting the service can’t be undone and data I delete can’t be restored.`. Then click the button which says `Remove Selected Services`. This is it.

[image: Step 3 - Removing google+]

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works as the account management page has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Google's **Account Management** page has changed recently.

To delete your Google+ profile:

1. Go to the [*My Account*](https://myaccount.google.com/) tool
2. Under "Account preferences", click "Delete your account or services"
3. Click "Delete products"

   - as a security measure, you'll be re-prompted for your password
4. There are currently three services you can remove from your account individually: Google+, YouTube, and Gmail; to remove your Google+ profile, click the trashcan icon next to Google+ and follow the directions