# Will this delete my entire Google Account or just Google plus?

Tags: google-plus, google-account

I don't know why can't they be more clear on this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous, but I believe that's saying it'll delete your profile, but not your account.

Comment: Google's been playing tricks like this ever since Google+ came out, a not-so-subtle way to discourage people from jumping off the google+ ship. I'm somewhat confident it's just going to delete the Google+ stuff, but I don't know what steps you went through to reach that screen so can't say for sure. And I'll bet Google *changes* the steps and warning screens regularly too. There is one sure-fire way to double-check before trying it on your "real" account. Make a **"test"** google account, add google+, then delete it with the screen/method you're asking about and see what happens to it.

Comment: Do you want to delete your entire profile, or just Google+? If the latter, see [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84366/354).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it'll just delete your public facing Google Profile and leave your actual Google Account intact.

[image: Google Profile != Google Account]

I imagine if you clicked any of the `learn more` links on that page you would be given the relevant information.

Comment: Note also that it says that your circles will be deleted but people in your circles will remain in your contacts.  That would require that you still have contacts for them to remain in.

Answer (score 1):

I made my son a gmail account six years ago.  Somewhere along the way the google+ account appeared, which I wasn't too happy about.  I did the deletion just as in your screenshot, and checked the "Yes I understand" box.  The profile disappeared, but the gmail account was still fine.

(The profile came back, by the way.  I suspect my son recreated it while at school.)